# Problema de lógica de javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, programación-funcional, lógica

Estoy practicando ejercicios de lógica de Javascript para mejorar en este lenguaje y prepararme para futuras entrevistas y me encuentro estancado en algo que tal vez pueda parecer básico, pero no encuentro la vuelta para resolverlo, no sé si alguien pudiera explicarme como resolver este problema.

El enunciado dice que: El objetivo de la función FormatString es quitar todos los caracteres especiales de la cadena de caracteres que viene como parámetro. Solo se permiten las 26 letras del alfabeto inglés,numeros de 0-9, espacios, guiones medios y bajos.

El programa es el siguiente:

```js
function FormatString(sentence) {
    let result = []; 

    sentence = sentence.toUpperCase(); 

    let i = 0; 
    let j = 0;

    while (i < sentence.lenght){
        if(
            (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && sentence.charCodeAt(i) <=90) || (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && sentence.charCodeAt(j) <= 57) || sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 32 ||
            sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 45
        ) {
            sentence[j] = result[i];
            j+=1;
        }
        i+=1;
    }
    return result.join(""); 
}
```

Se supone que hay errores en el ejercicio, pero no logro identificarlos, me gustaría hacer que el código funcionara, disculpen si es algo muy básico, pero todavía estoy aprendiendo. gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te indican en otra respuesta, las expresiones regulares son la mejor opción.
Pero hablando específicamente de tu función, quiero mencionarte un par de cosas:

- La primera y más importante, escribiste mal "length" en la condición del While, por lo que nunca estaba entrando al bucle
- El uso de la variable "j" no le veo funcionalidad
- Para agregar valores a un array, se utiliza la función push()
- También te hizo falta el 95 que es el guión bajo

  ```
  function FormatString(sentence) {
    let result = [];     
    sentence = sentence.toUpperCase(); 

    let i = 0;     

    while (i < sentence.length){
        if(
            (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && sentence.charCodeAt(i) <=90) || 
            (sentence.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && sentence.charCodeAt(i) <= 57)|| 
            sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 32 || sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 95 || 
            sentence.charCodeAt(i) == 45
        ) 
        {
            result.push(sentence[i])            
        }
        i++
    }
    return result.join(""); 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero que utilices expresiones regulares. Son muy útiles y pueden facilitarse mucho las cosas. Pero no son fáciles ni intuitivas.
Por ejemplo:

```js
function formatStrinf(s){
  return s.replace(/([^\w _-])/ig,'');
}
console.log(formatStrinf("abc!$% ABC`çñ 1234-_<>!"));
```